# Confusion regarding solving inequality $\log_2(x-1) \geq 3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Confusion regarding solving inequality  $\log_2(x-1) \geq 3$. Now i got answer to be $[9,\infty]$. But i don't see why we have to take intersection with domain at the end?

Thanks

Comment: Intersection with which domain at the end? The answer is $[9,\infty)$.

Comment: Intersection with domain of original inequality i.e domain of log

Comment: The domain of the logarithm function is $(0,\infty)$ Hence, it is only required that $x \in (1,\infty)$ for the function to be well defined. We already got $[9,\infty)$, and $[9,\infty) \cap (1,\infty) = [9,\infty)$, so even after taking intersection we are left with the same thing

Comment: But why take intersection is my question

Comment: Otherwise the logartithm would not make sense? For example, $\log (-x^2 - 3)$ cannot be defined at all.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, take the necessary condition

$$x-1 > 0$$

hence

$$x > 1$$
otherwise you cannot proceed.

Now, exponentiate in base $2$:

$$2^{\log_2(x-1)} \geq 2^3$$

$$x-1 \geq 8$$

$$x \geq 9$$

Hence the domain is given by $[9, +\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of notation really. This also seems like a homework problem because you said that you got the answer to be [9, $\infty$] yet you don't see why you chose to include ] at the end?

There is a question thread that covers this quite extensively.

[Interval Notation and Infinity- Closed or Open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681954/interval-notation-and-infinity-closed-or-open)